# Adding Custom Gallery in WIX Code connected to WIX Events

Tags: custom-element, velo

I have been working with WIX for a while but never used the code or CORVID feature.
I want to create a homepage with a gallery of images connected to my WIX events. I have successfully done that with the DATABASE connection and now my event images, title and descriptions show in the gallery.
Now the problem is that I cannot give format to the text, I think I can do this with CORVID but I have no idea how, can anyone help me? 
PS I am not a developer so if you can provide a code sample it will make it easier for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize design elements of the gallery using Corvid. Check the documentation for Gallery available here: https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/$w.Gallery.html